# csv file read - every single character in one single list

Tags: python, file, csv, file-read

I am rather new to python and could really need some help (I did not find anything that helped me by now).

I want to read a csv-file to a `list`, but unfortunately my output is not as expected. Instead of having a list like:

`[[Weiz;61744],[Deutschlandsberg;5645]]`

I have a list that looks like this:

`[['W'],['e'],['i'], etc.]`

My code looks like this:

```
def readCSV(file):
    for row in open(file,"r+"):
        ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(row)
        csvFile = csv.reader(ftpstream.read().decode('latin-1'))
        data = [row for row in csvFile]
        for row in data:
            print(row)
```

Can anybody please tell me why it is not working? I am really struggling right now...

Comment: Please format the code

Comment: Already done, I am sorry.

Comment: `for row in data` is breaking down each line by character further. Can you show what one line of `data` looks like?

Comment: I edited it in post :-)

Comment: @IamnotaRabbit don't add picture when you could do it with text. You don't need to write "Added" or "Edit" or "Edit 42.3.1" or "I come back in 5 minute" :p.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function `csv.reader` expects to receive a list of lines, not a single string (such as would be returned by `ftpstream.read().decode('latin-1')`).  If you replace:

```
csvFile = csv.reader(ftpstream.read().decode('latin-1'))
```

with

```
csvFile = csv.reader(ftpstream.read().decode('latin-1').split('\n'))
```

I believe it will work as you expect.

Comment: That worked just perfectly fine! Thanks a lot!!
But I still don't quite get it. I read through some python tutorials considering csv-file read and I think I didn't see anything like that (but maybe there was and I didn't get it). What makes my file different?

Comment: Nothing different about your file.  `csv.reader` expects to get an iterator over lines -- if it's passed a file object or if it's passed a list of strings (one per line), it works fine.  If it's passed a single string, then it tries to iterate over it, but iterating over a string iterates over the individual characters.  In this case, `csv.reader` acts as if you've passed it a file with one character per line, and you get weird output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your file, I think using `readLine()` instead of `read()` should get you to what you want. For example:

```
csvFile = csv.reader(ftpstream.readLine().decode('latin-1'))
```

instead of

```
csvFile = csv.reader(ftpstream.read().decode('latin-1'))
```

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately the output stays the same :-(