# Trying to read s3 response body as a nested list, getting characters as individual elements in nested list

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Currently, I have a 435kb CSV file (3450 rows) in S3. I am trying to download it within AWS Lambda's /tmp directory and read it as a nested list. I've tried a different decoding per the post here: [csv file read - every single character in one single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029964/csv-file-read-every-single-character-in-one-single-list), but it didn't seem to work. The goal is mainly to download one CSV from s3 and it as a nested list with another nested list (CSV rows) and apply the delta to one of them and then upload it back to s3.

Ex of CSV File Input: [name, db, server],[name1, mysql, x_1001],[name2, aurora, x_1032],

Ex of output from print: "n, a, m, e", "d, b", "s, e, r, v, e, r", etc.

Relevent code is as follows:

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-east-1", config=Config(connect_timeout=5, retries={'max_attempts': 0}
response = s3.get_object(Bucket="myuniquebucketname-889", Key="/someprefix/mycsvfile.csv")
csvContent = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(True)
csvList = []
print(csvContent)
for row in csv.reader(csvContent):
    if row[0] == "some_value":
        csvList.append(row[0])

for row in otherNestedList:
    if row not in csvList:
        csvList.append(row)
```

Comment: Can you please provide your output?